# Präfixbedeutungen

Tags: meaning, prefix

Ich weiß was die Suffixe (z.B. "-keit", "-ung", "-schaft") bedeuten, aber die Präfixe (z.B. "ver-", "be-", "er-", "ein-") haben mich etwas verwirrt. Gibt es irgendwo eine komplette Liste der Präfixbedeutungen?

Zum Beispiel, "kaufen" heißt "to buy" und "verkaufen" heißt "to sell", also könnte ich denken dass "ver-" bedeutet "reverse" oder etwas ähnliches... aber "lassen" heißt "to let" und "verlassen" heißt "to leave", also ist mein vorheriger Eindrück eindeutig falsch.

Ich weiß dass "ge-" mit dem Partizip Perfekt benutzt wird, aber was bedeutet der Rest?

Vielen Dank.

Comment: Wie du bereits richtig erkannt hast, ist die Sache nicht so einfach. Viele Präfixverben sind sprachlich so weit verschmolzen, dass eine Trennung in zwei Einzelbedeutungen keinen Sinn mehr macht. Zum Beispiel hat "verlassen" semantisch so gut wie nichts mehr mit "lassen" zu tun. Am besten behandelt man die Wörter als jeweils eigenständige Lexikoneinträge, die nur zufällig ähnlich klingen.

Comment: Noch extremeres Beispiel: "verlieren". Kann man nicht mehr in "ver" + "lieren" trennen, weil es gar kein Verb "lieren" (mehr) gibt.

Comment: "verlassen" ist durchaus Teil eines allgemeinen Trends. Wer "Lass mich!" sagt, *will* allein sein. Wer *verlassen* wurde, wollte es eher nicht. "ver-" bezeichnet oft eine negativ angesehene oder verschlimmernde Handlung. Nur eben nicht immer!

Comment: Vielen Dank euch beide für deine Kommentare. Danke auch an Hubert Schölnast und den Rest für meine Frage als doppelte zu markieren; die andere Frage hat gute Kommentare und eine sehr interessante Antwort. Ich habe viel gelernt. :)